# Problem when trying to extract data with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, extract

Hello I am trying to extract the odds of this webpage :
https://www.unibet.fr/sport/football

Here is my python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np
import os

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.unibet.fr/sport/football')

odds = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(@class, "ui-touchlink-needsclick price odd-price")]')))]

print(odds, '\n')

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

The output gives me that :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./azerty.py", line 26, in <module>
    odds = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(@class, "ui-touchlink-needsclick price odd-price")]')))]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

This script run perfectly with other webpage but not in this case.
Some help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reason being you are getting timeout is as your page is infinite loading page i.e. new elements are getting loaded if you go to bottom of page. Now even if few elements are there in DOM, they are not being located by selenium, As a result you are getting time out. Try to first load all elements and then locate them.

```
driver.get('https://www.unibet.fr/sport/football')
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@data-track-action="start_page"]'))) #Wait for page to load

#Scroll till page is loaded completely
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(2)
    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
#Get the elements
odds = [my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath( '//span[contains(@class, "ui-touchlink-needsclick price odd-price")]')]
print(odds, '\n')

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

**Out Put:**

[image]